Best methods to stratify data into 4 groups (unsupervised manner) using a set/combination of variables
I'm trying to stratify a set of patients according to possible molecular subtypes of cancer. Now, I know all these patients have a type of cancer, but the goal is to (in a unsupervised manner) cluster those patients into 4 possible subtypes. So, say we have the variables:
age + metastasis + trt_dosage + Gene 1 + Gene 2 + Gene 3 + Gene 4 + ... where Gene 1,2,3,4 are supposed to be "markers" of these subtypes. Now, from the literature it is thought that those subtypes are characterized by the presence or absence of those 4 genes. Which methods are there so that this combination of variables would allow to best stratify patients in each of these subtypes?
What I've been trying:

Using KMeans to stratify each patient into one of the four available groups
Using these cluster labels to train a RF model so that we have target (labels from step 1) ~ all other variables and then plot the decision algorithm for each sample (so we can see a decision tree on how these decisions were made)

But I'm not entirely sure if this is correct. After this, I'm also trying to create a nomogram (i.e. a logistic regression) that provides a score based on the combination of all the variables just to see if it would help stratify those groups better, but not entirely sure how to go about this.
Given that the subtype of this cancer "may" be associated with the expression of each gene (in this case I'm using the lognormalized expression of each gene), would there be a way somehow to constraint so that those subtypes are likely to be of a cluster type based on this expression? Not quite sure how to go about this :)
Thank you!
